# How can I return category, revenue, top brands and their revenue for each category in a single row?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to return category, revenue, top brand, revenue for the top brand, second brand, revenue for second brand, etc. up to 5+, ideally all in a single row for that category. Right now i have a row for each of the top brands

```
SELECT
      cats.category
      cats.revenue
      brands.rank
      brands.brand
      brands.revenue_brand
FROM
      (SELECT
      category, sum(revenue) as revenue_total
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY category
      ) cats 
JOIN 
      (SELECT
      category,
      brand,
      sum(revenue) as revenue_brand
      rank () over (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue_brand DESC) as rank
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY category, brand
      ) brands on cats.category = brands.category
WHERE brands.rank <=5
```

How can I create one row for each category instead of one row for each rank?

Comment: You don't provide sample data ot desired result which is probbaly why you have no answers, **but also** I suggest you read [this blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/maria_zakourdaev/archive/2017/11/07/dynamic-pivot-in-amazon-redshift-don-t-blame-databases-for-disappointing-you-blame-yourself-for-expecting-too-much-from-them.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This might not meet all of your expectations, and as I have no access to redshift I can't do any testing. It appears that redshift doesn't allow for ["dynamic sql"[(http://sqlblog.com/blogs/maria_zakourdaev/archive/2017/11/07/dynamic-pivot-in-amazon-redshift-don-t-blame-databases-for-disappointing-you-blame-yourself-for-expecting-too-much-from-them.aspx) and this means you simply cannot get "dynamic headings" (i.e. a heading for `brand-rank-1 |  brand-rank-2 |   brand-rank-3 |` etc.

With this in mind the "old fashioned" way to achieve a pivot was to use "conditional aggregates" (case expressions inside aggregation functions).

```
SELECT
        cats.category
      , max(case when rn = 1 then brands.brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 1 then brands.revenue_brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 2 then brands.brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 2 then brands.revenue_brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 3 then brands.brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 3 then brands.revenue_brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 4 then brands.brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 4 then brands.revenue_brand end)
      , max(case when rn = 5 then brands.brand end)     
      , max(case when rn = 5 then brands.revenue_brand end)
      , cats.revenue
FROM (
      SELECT
            category
          , SUM(revenue) AS revenue_total
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY
            category
) cats
JOIN (
      SELECT
            category
          , brand
          , SUM(revenue)                                                          AS revenue_brand
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue_brand DESC) AS rn
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY
            category
          , brand
) brands ON cats.category = brands.category
WHERE brands.rn <= 5
group by 
        cats.category
      , cats.revenue
```

Note because rank() can produce gaps in numbers and/or can have "equal rank" values, I changed to the use of row_number() instead which will always return 5 rows of 1 to 5.